# What is better to use for mapping value to Map of functions: tail recursion or foreach?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I want to map functions from my functions library (`Map` called as `chain`) to input string `str`. Also that functions (`Twitter.removeRT`, ...) are regex which replace substrings in input `str`. I think it is better to save that regex-functions in Map like in my example.

### So, the code:

Tail recursion variant

```
  def filterTwitter2 (str: String): String = {

    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def recFilter(str: String, chain: Map[String, (String) => String]): String = {
      chain.headOption match {
        case Some(v) =>
          val filteredString = v._2(str)
          recFilter(filteredString, chain.tail)
        case None => str
      }
    }

    val chain = Map[String,(String) => String](
      "f1"-> Twitter.removeRT,
      "f2"-> Twitter.removeNickName,
      "f3"-> Twitter.removeURL,
      "f6"-> Emoticons.removePunctRepetitions,
      "f7"-> Emoticons.removeHorizontalEmoticons,
      "f9"-> Emoticons.normalizeEmoticons,
      "f10"-> Beautify.removeCharRepetitions,
      "f12"-> Beautify.removeNSpaces
    )

    recFilter(str, chain)
  }
```

`foreach` variant

```
  def filterTwitter (str: String): String = {
    var tmp = str
    val chain = Map[String,(String) => String](
      "f1"-> Twitter.removeRT,
      "f2"-> Twitter.removeNickName,
      "f3"-> Twitter.removeURL,
      "f6"-> Emoticons.removePunctRepetitions,
      "f7"-> Emoticons.removeHorizontalEmoticons,
      "f9"-> Emoticons.normalizeEmoticons,
      "f10"-> Beautify.removeCharRepetitions,
      "f12"-> Beautify.removeNSpaces
    )
    chain.foreach {
      case (name, func) => tmp = func(tmp)
    }
    tmp
  }
```

### So, the questions:

1. Is it normal to save functions in map? What can be better for it?
2. What better: tail recursion variant or variant with `foreach`?
3. Maybe there is any better solution for that problem?

Comment: 2nd: In this case `foreach` is very easy to understand, use it. But it will be more clear if you define `var tmp` 1 line before `chain.foreach`.

Answer (score 2):

You never use your `Map` to lookup a filter function by its key. If you don't need any of the keys then you don't really need a `Map`.

```
def filterTwitter(str :String) :String =
  List(Twitter.removeRT
      ,Twitter.removeNickName
      ,Twitter.removeURL
      ,Emoticons.removePunctRepetitions
      ,Emoticons.removeHorizontalEmoticons
      ,Emoticons.normalizeEmoticons
      ,Beautify.removeCharRepetitions
      ,Beautify.removeNSpaces
      ).foldRight(str)(_(_))
```

---

### EXPLANATION

The 1st underscore is an element from the `List` that is being folded. Because this is a fold **Right**, it will start with the last element (`removeNSpaces`) and work toward the head (`removeRT`).

The 2nd underscore is the result from the previous invocation and it is being passed as an argument to the filter function. (Actually it's a little more complicated than that, but this is an easy way to think about it.)

So this is what's going down:

```
removeNSpaces(str)             ===> resStr1
removeCharRepetitions(resStr1) ===> resStr2
normalizeEmoticons(resStr2)    ===> resStr3
. . .
removeRT(prevResStr)           ===> finalResStr
```

Comment: Yes it is, so you here, with `List`, right. Also i will look at `foldRight(str)(_(_))` to understand how it works.

Comment: It's a syntactic abbreviation of: `foldRight(str){case (f, s) => f(s)}`

Comment: can you  explain what is 1st underscore in brackets and what is 2nd underscore which in brackets of brackets? as i suppose, 1st - is element of list which in my case is function (like `Twitter.removeRT`), but i can`t understand what that function from list applay in place of 2nd underscore.

Comment: @Gudsaf; See my update.